# return View("viewname") not returning the view specified

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Using the SPA Template I'm trying to get the `Login` POST method to return the `VerifyEmail` View if the user has not verified their email yet.

While debugging you can see the `return View("VerifyEmail")` being called, however, I'm returned to "/" and the `VerifyEmail` view is not being returned.

I have verified that the View is in the correct folder Views > Account.

Is there some automatic routing configuration I should look for? Why isn't my View being returned?

```
[HttpPost]
[AllowAnonymous]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public async Task<ActionResult> LogOn(LogOnVM model, string returnUrl)
{
    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        return View(model);

    switch (await SignInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(model.UserName, model.Password, model.RememberMe, true))
    {
        case SignInStatus.Success:
            MyUser user = await UserManager.FindByNameAsync(model.UserName);
            if (!await UserManager.IsEmailConfirmedAsync(user.UserName))
                return View("VerifyEmail");
            else
                return RedirectToLocal(returnUrl);
        //other cases ignored for brevity
    }
}
```

I tried to add this, but didn't help at all:

```
public ActionResult VerifyEmail()
{
    return View();
}
```

I was searching and found this in my code, obviously there because of the default template:

```
public override Task ValidateClientRedirectUri(OAuthValidateClientRedirectUriContext context)
{
    if (context == null)
        throw new ArgumentNullException("context");

    if (context.ClientId == _publicClientId)
    {
        Uri expectedRootUri = new Uri(context.Request.Uri, "/");

        if (expectedRootUri.AbsoluteUri == context.RedirectUri)
        {
            context.Validated();
        }
        else if (context.ClientId == "web")
        {
            var expectedUri = new Uri(context.Request.Uri, "/");
            context.Validated(expectedUri.AbsoluteUri);
        }
    }
    return Task.FromResult<object>(null);
}
```

Could this be what's causing the problem?

Comment: Have you tried using `return RedirectToAction("VerifyEmail");` instead?

Comment: @Jonnus, yes, I experienced the same "error"

Comment: Where is the VerifyEmail view located?

Comment: @enki.dev the view is under Views, under a folder of the same name as the Controller's

Comment: @cFrozenDeath, try commenting the code in `ValidateClientRedirectUri`, although it shouldn't be that because `return View("...");` doesn't redirect, it renders the view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Commenting the code in my last edit did not work, but I see that removing **?ReturnUrl=%2F** from /account/logon?ReturnUrl=%2F does the trick. The ReturnUrl is passed as `routeValues` under `@Html.BeginForm` for the LogOn View. I figured I'd just pass `null` to `routeValues` which fixed the issue!