# Using @Html.Action in Razor view successfully goes to the new controller but after executing controller does not go to the new controller's view

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

I am using MVC .net framework and I'm very new to asp.net mvc, apologies in advance.
My query is I am able to successfully load a csv file in my first controller and view. From my first view I then go to my `NextController` which then does the main processing. Till here all good. From here I am now having to move this to my next controller's view, `FxProcess`. Instead it returns to the existing view and complains of namespace issue with the new model `FxOrder`. Where am I going wrong? Here are my controllers and views:

HomeController.cs

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    // GET: Home
    public ActionResult Upload()
    {
        return View();
    }

    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Upload(HttpPostedFileBase upload, SecTypeDetails secTypeUsed)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {

            if (upload != null && upload.ContentLength > 0)
            {
                if (upload.FileName.EndsWith(".csv"))
                {
                    var csvParser = new TextFieldParser(upload.InputStream);
                    var fileName = upload.FileName;
                    var newview = new Trade0Tron.web.Models.SecTypeDetails { sectype = secTypeUsed.sectype, csvParser = csvParser, fileName = fileName };
                    return View(newview);
                }
                else
                {
                    ModelState.AddModelError("File", "This file format is not supported");
                    return View();
                }
            }
            else
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError("File", "Please Upload Your file");
            }
        }
        return View();
    }
}
```

Upload.cshtml

```
@model Trade0Tron.web.Models.SecTypeDetails
@using System.Data;

<h2>Upload File</h2>

@using (Html.BeginForm("Upload", "Home", null, FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    @Html.ValidationSummary()

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="file" id="dataFile" name="upload" />
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="submit" value="Upload" class="btn btn-default" />
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-8">
            <div class="form-group">
                Select SecType to run
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                @Html.EnumDropDownListFor(
                    x => x.sectype,
                    new { @class = "form-control" })
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    if (Model != null)
    {
        @Html.Action("FxProcess", "Next", Model)
    }
}
```

NextController.cs

```
public class NextController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult FxProcess(SecTypeDetails secTypeUsed)
    {
        var wk = new Work();
        var fxOrder = wk.FxFileProcessing("", secTypeUsed.fileName, "csv", secTypeUsed.sectype.ToString(), false, secTypeUsed.csvParser);
        return View("FxProcess", fxOrder);
    }
}
```

and the corresponding cshtml is as below

```html
@model Models.Fx.FxOrder
@using System.Data;

<h2>Upload File</h2>

@using (Html.BeginForm("FxProcess", "FxTrade"))
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    @Html.ValidationSummary()

    if (Model != null)
    {
        @Html.Action("GetResult", "FxResult", Model)
```

I would ideally like the result of the`NextController` action to go to its corresponding view, which then goes to a result controller. Which again has a result view to display the result. Also note the NextController has a new model Models.Fx.FxOrder.

Comment: Hard to understand. Does `return View("FxProcess", fxOrder);`  not going to FxProcess.cshtml? Is it helpful?: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33634897/return-viewviewname-not-returning-the-view-specified

Answer (score 0):

Routing may depend on folder structure. When returning View() you can indicate the full path. `return View("~/Views/Next/FxProcess", fxOrder);`